# Passing a variable to an axios request in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, post, axios

I have this axios `get` method that retrieves all the playlists a user has from an endpoint:

```
getUserPlaylists() {
        axios
            .get("/v1/users/"+ JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).id +"/playlists", {headers: { Authorization: localStorage.getItem("apiKey") }})
            .then((response) => {
                var playlists = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < response.data.items.length; i++) {
                    playlists[i] = response.data.items[i];
                }
                console.log(response);
                this.setState({
                    playlists: playlists,
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log("Get Error"));
    }
```

which is working pretty fine, I have also written a `post` method to add a current video to a playlist
using the `videoID` and the `playlistID`

```
addToPlaylist(playlistID){
        const uri = "/v1/users/"+ JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).id +"/playlists/"+ playlistID +"/videos"
      axios
          .post(uri, {id: window.location.href.substring(28) }, {headers: { Authorization: localStorage.getItem("apiKey") }})
          .then((response) => {
              console.log(response);
          })
          .catch((error) => console.log("Get Error"));
    }
```

I tried calling the `post` method in the `render` method as following:

```
{this.state.playlists.map((playlist) => (<ul key={playlist.id}><Button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.addToPlaylist.bind(playlist.id)}>Add video to Playlist <b><i>{playlist.name}</i></b></Button></ul>))}
```

everything works fine, excepts when I click a button to call the `post` method I get the following error

```
POST http://localhost:3000/v1/users/867/playlists/[object%20Object]/videos 404 (Not Found)
```

I can't understand why the `post` method is not correctly getting the `playlistID`

Comment: `.bind(playlist.id)` is making that value `this` inside the function. The *argument* is the click event.

Comment: How to change the argument to `playlist.id` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MDN Docs:

> The [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

The first argument bind takes is the context(the value of this), in your current scenario you can set it to null.

```
onClick={this.addToPlaylist.bind(null, playlist.id)}
```

or you can use an arrow function

```
onClick={() => this.addToPlaylist(playlist.id)}
```